# minimal polynomial of a matrix with no real roots

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to have a matrix in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ with a quadratic minimal polynomial $m(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ possessing no real roots? Does this correspond to no real eigenvalues, or can the characteristic polynomial be, for example, $p(x)=m(x)(x-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Consider what the rational canonical form of such a matrix would be.  It would have a block of size $2$ for the minimal polynomial, which would force it to have a block of size $1$.  This block of size $1$ would correspond to a linear invariant factor that must divide the minimal polynomial.  But the minimal polynomial is assumed irreducible, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: Why would the linear invariant factor have to divide the minimal rather than characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Smaller invariant factors are chosen to divide larger ones. The minimal polynomial is the largest invariant factor.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor).